# Apply code to input box on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I have a popup that appears when a user clicks on a link. This opens a popup that is a different url then the page the user is viewing.

What I am trying to figure out is how to apply some code when a user clicks a link called "Click to Apply" on the popup into an input box on the original page.

Here is my code.

**Original Page**

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>" method="post">
    <div class="discount">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Discount Codes') ?></h2>
        <div class="discount-form">
            <label for="coupon_code"><?php echo $this->__('Enter your coupon code if you have one.') ?></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="remove" id="remove-coupone" value="0" />
            <div class="input-box">
                <input class="input-text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCouponCode()) ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?>" class="button" onclick="discountForm.submit(false)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?></span></span></button>

                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Get Coupon') ?>" class="button" onclick="return popitup('http://127.0.0.1:8888/giftreg/activecoupons')" value="<?php echo $this->__('Get Coupon') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Get Coupon') ?></span></span></button>


                <?php if(strlen($this->getCouponCode())): ?>
                    &nbsp; <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?>" class="button" onclick="discountForm.submit(true)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=500,width=1000');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

**POPUP Page**

```
<a href="" value="SomeCodeToApply" class="bottom"><strong>Click To Apply</strong></a>
```

When the above link is clicked on, I would like it to apply the value to the following input field on the original page.

```
<input class="input-text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCouponCode()) ?>" />
```

Finally, when the user clicks on the link to apply it, it should close the popup.

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: You want add the value of your input when any click on "bottom" class where exactly you want add the val?

Comment: I want to add the value to the original page in the input that has the id `coupon_code`

Comment: Keyword: `window.opener`

Comment: Oh, and on click it should also close the popup

Comment: Ok, see my answer, but I'm not sure if you can understand.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks so much buddy! If you post that and a short explanation for others I'll accept your answer. That worked great for me and exactly what I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.opener` points to the window instance a popup window was opened from (using `window.open`).

So when the user clicks on the “apply” link/button in your popup, you can use that to access your form element in the opening page, set the value, and then close your popup afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Soo, no use a popup...

You need a button like "view coupons" or something...

soo, you click the button

```
<a id="view" href="#">View Copuns</a> //your buttonn
<div id="myCoupons" style="display:none;"> //your div coupons
    <p>COUPON12334</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn_coupon" id="<? echo $id_coupon_or_coupon_text_etc?>">buton</a>
    <p>COUPON123214</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn_coupon" id="<? echo $id_coupon_or_coupon_text_etc?>">buton</a>
    <p>COUPON5343</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn_coupon" id="<? echo $id_coupon_or_coupon_text_etc?>">buton</a>
</div>
//Tour input with the value coupon
<input type="hidden" id="coupon" name="coupon"/>
//your script
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
$('#view').click(function(){ //When you click view, show the div
   $('#myCoupons').show(); //Show the div of coupons.
});

$('.btn_coupon').click(function(){ //When you click on a btn_coupon, close the div and put the val of your coupon in input hidden
  var value = $(this).attr("id"));
  alert("You click in the coupon "+value;
  //you can put this val in a input hidden
  $('#coupon').val(value);
  $('#myCoupons').hide(); //CLOSE THE DIV OF COUPONS
});
</script>
```

THen you can received in your php file like $_POST['coupon'] or $_GET when you click in submit form.

Comment: I added that to the popup page but it didn't work. You remember that the popup page and the actual page are two different links. Does that matter? Or would it be best to add the popup info inside the original page?

Comment: I think it's always best to all in the same window. I'm not use PopUp, but I think that you can use a Modal with html5, I don't understand that you try really, you can use $.ajax for get a php value.

Comment: Ok, so now I just have to figure out how to pull it in on the original page using ajax right?

Comment: you need create a php file and write $coupon = $this->htmlEscape($this->getCouponCode(); then echo $coupon; <-- this is your data with ajax .done
But I question to myself, is this necessary ?? you can generate the coupon in the same page ? is really necessary generate the coupon in a popUp or another page?

Comment: Yes, I have to generate it in another page. By default Magento does not list the available coupons. I have created an extension that will show the available coupons. In the user's cart, they can click on a link that I created to show the coupons (hence, the popup) and then I need it to apply to the coupon input field as mentioned. Make since?

Comment: Ok, see my answer, is one alternative. And I recommend to u, no use popUp. Now, you can use a slideDown() jquery function, with this, u can use an animation to show() or hide();

Comment: I'm getting TypeError 'undefined' is not a function so it is not working. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to avoid popup windows if at all possible most people use ad-block and it will prevent vital information from being displayed.

Instead use Jquery Dialog or a similar solution. You'll need Jquery UI, I didn't include the CSS so it looks crappy. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8jK7f/

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirm Purchase">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Your coupon code is:<span id="my_code"> </span></p>
</div>
<a href="#" id="coupon_code" value="488452345" class="bottom"><strong>Click To Open Popup</strong></a>
<a href="#" class="closePopup"><strong>Close Popup from page</strong></a>
```

### Javascript

```
 $('.bottom').click(function(){ 
      var value = $('#coupon_code').attr('value'); 
       //append code
      $('#my_code').html(value);
       //open-popup
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );

    });


        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          autoOpen:false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Option_1": function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });

      $( ".closePopup" ).click(function() {
          $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "close" );
        });
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError 'undefined' is not a function so it is not working. Any idea why?